# Empty ASP.Net application blank page refresh increasing memory usage

Tags: asp.net, performance-testing, w3wp

I created an empty ASP.Net project (.Net framework 4.0) and added a blank Default.aspx page to it. Did a Release build and hosted it on IIS (IIS 8, Windows 8.1) with a separate application pool created just for it.

When I refresh the Default.aspx on the browser continuously, the memory usage (Private working set) for the w3wp process in task manager keeps on increasing. The very first page request spawns the w3wp.exe with around 15 MB memory usage but from that point onwards it just keeps increasing in very small increments. I was able to get passed 100 MB by refreshing the browser page constantly.

Surely there should be a valid reason for this. Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Did you ever find a cause for this?

Comment: Nope. Still in the back of my head though... :-)